# How to use "width auto" and "float" to align divs?

Tags: css, width, css-float

i would like to have a container (with some text) on the left of the page, **that adapts itself** with the space available, and 2 sidebars following on the right (i'm using Wordpress).
(The 2 sidebars work fine with `float`. ) So i tried `width:auto` on the container.

But it does not adapt itself with the rest of the space available (it takes all the page width). If i set the width to *70%*, it fits the space on the index page, but if i click on an article, i only have 1 sidebar left, so there is a blank space between the text and the sidebar.

Do you know how to fix this?

```
#container { /* the text */
    overflow:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

#primary { /* first sidebar */
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:right;
    width:250px;
}


#second { /* second sidebar */
    border:1px solid red;
    background:white;
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    float:right;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Thanks

---

EDIT :

let's say i'm using this instead of the wordpress sidebars : i still can't manage to make it work, could someone have a look with this simple code? there're 2 boxes : the green one and the red one...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
        <body>

            <div style="position:relative; width:700px; margin:0 auto;">
                <div style="width:auto; border:1px solid green;">i would like to have a container (with some text) on the left of the page, that adapts itself with the space available, and 2 sidebars following on the right (i'm using Wordpress). (The 2 sidebars work fine with float. ) So i tried width:auto on the container.

But it does not adapt itself with the rest of the space available (it takes all the page width). If i set the width to 70%, it fits the space on the index page, but if i click on an article, i only have 1 sidebar left, so there is a blank space between the text and the sidebar.</div>

<div style="width:20%; float:right; border:1px solid red;">blablabla</div>
            </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A very simple way to do this would be to edit the template for articles, so you have a special CSS for the container when there's only one sidebar.

Comment: @OptimusCrime : thanks, can you be more specific? should i use a "style=" attribute in the html? will it override the css file?

Comment: Are the two side bars inside your container?

Comment: @Paul : The articles have a special template. If you add for example a class to the body like `<body class="onesidebar">` you could write something like `body.onesidebar #container` in you CSS

Comment: @Jack : hi Jack, no there're outside, i edited my post above, maybe you could have a look? thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, i found it out : put the text at the end, use overflow:hidden and auto, and float right on the small container on the right, thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found it out : put the text at the end, use overflow:hidden and auto, and float right on the small container on the right, thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

A width:auto is the default value so it won't be doing anything other than what a DIV would do as standard, which is to fill the available width since it's a block level element. This changes when you float it and it will wrap its content so could be any width up to the maximum width.

I think the trouble you're running in to is mixing percentage widths and fixed widths. I can see what you're trying to do - have a fixed width sidebar (or two) and the rest of the page flexible. It was really easy to do this back in the table-based layout days but let's not go there!

Sounds like you want a fluid layout but with 2 fixed with columns. Might be worth having a read of this article to see if anything suits what you're trying to do: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/

Comment: Although these days I'd usually recommend a responsive layout based on a grid system. An elastic layout at different sizes for various devices works well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it does not change anything with 20% on each sidebar, and width:auto on the container, would you have any other idea?

Comment: If you stick to all percentage layouts then you'd do something like container:60% sidebar1:20% sidebar2:20%. Width:auto is not going to do anything for you as it doesn't mean 'automatically fill the rest of the space'. It is causing the container to fill the whole 100% width and pushing the sidebars below it.

Comment: thanks howard10 for your help, i'm quite new with css, could you have a look to my edit in my first post above? i edited it with a simple example... maybe you'll have the answer? thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use display:table on parent div. Then display:table-cell on the children. They will align the way they would in a table.

```
#container { /* the text */
    overflow:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    // float:left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#primary { /* first sidebar */
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    // float:right;
    width:250px;
    vertical-align:top;
}


#second { /* second sidebar */
    border:1px solid red;
    background:white;
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    // float:right;
    margin-left:15px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```